# How I ignore the elements NaN in matrix for polynomial adjustment and use the "a" and "b" of the equation of polyfit?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with size 9x27. Each column correspond a simple variable, I need to plot a variable one with example:

```
m = [7.0000   10.0307
 8.0000    5.4601
 9.0000    4.2331
10.0000    2.8221
11.0000    4.0491
12.0000    5.2147
13.0000    7.1779
14.0000   13.0675
15.0000       NaN...]

plot(m(:,1),m(:,2))
```

Posteriorly, I need to adjust of polynomial(2) "quadratic". However, my numbers of the equation not out for me.

```
a = polyfit(m(:,1),m(:,2),2)
a =

   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

I would like to delete the NaN elements for so that numbers of the equation can be used after.
I need to find the minimal value for the adjust polynomial. The derivative zero. "b/2*a".
I hope have a been clear!
I thank everyone's attention.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the presence of a NaN means the rest of the row is useless, it's probably best to simply filter out those rows:

```
validrows = ~any(isnan(m), 2);
a = polyfit(m(validrows,1), m(validrows,2), 2)
```