# My end result of the polyfit is NaN, but I delet NaN of the matrix and I left the same size, you help me?

Tags: matlab

Example data:

```
 3.0000    4.8500    3.2700    4.8900    3.3100    4.9000    2.7500    4.8600    2.9400
 5.0000    4.9200         0    4.8900         0    4.9000         0    4.9000         0
 7.0000    4.9000         0    4.8600         0    4.9000         0    4.9300         0
 8.0000         0    1.7800         0    2.6800         0    2.1300         0    2.8000
 9.0000         0    1.3800         0    1.6300         0    1.2200         0    1.8200
10.0000         0    0.9200         0    1.3100         0    0.9500         0    1.4200
11.0000         0    1.3200         0    1.3100         0    1.0100         0    1.7500
12.0000         0    1.7000         0    1.4200         0    1.1400         0    2.3900
13.0000         0    2.3400         0    2.3800         0    2.1400         0    4.4800
14.0000         0    4.2600         0    2.7400         0    2.8300         0    4.7300
15.0000         0         0         0         0         0    3.4600         0    5.0400

Columns 10 through 17

4.9900    3.0700    4.9200    3.0300    4.9600    3.7400    4.9600    3.4400
4.9000    3.5800    4.9800    3.9000    4.9500    3.0000         0    3.5800
4.9200         0    4.9500         0         0         0         0         0
     0    3.1300         0    3.9900         0    1.8300         0    3.3800
     0    2.4800         0    2.2000         0    1.2800         0    2.9900
     0    1.6100         0    1.8800         0    0.9200         0    2.7500
     0    2.2000         0    1.7000         0    1.0200         0    2.2100
     0    2.3800         0    1.6700         0    1.4600         0    2.7500
     0         0         0    1.9500         0    1.5800         0    2.9600
     0         0         0    3.0000         0    2.6700         0         0
     0         0         0    3.2800         0    4.3400         0         0
```

CODE :

```
function [LacMin] = lac(dat)

Cal = 5.0; %Valor de Calibração;

StLido = dat(1:3,2:2:end); %Identificando Padroes;

StLido(StLido==0) = NaN; %Exluindo zeros;

Pmed = nanmean(StLido); %Padrão Médio;

pa = Pmed(1,1); %Selecionando padrão para cada indivíduo;

pb = Pmed(1,2);

pc = Pmed(1,3);

pd = Pmed(1,4);

pe = Pmed(1,5);

pf = Pmed(1,6);

pg = Pmed(1,7);

ph = Pmed(1,8);

% pi = Pmed(1,9);

% pj = Pmed(1,10);

% pk = Pmed(1,11);

% pl = Pmed(1,12);

% pm = Pmed(1,13);

% pn = Pmed(1,14);

% po = Pmed(1,15);

% pp = Pmed(1,16);

% pq = Pmed(1,17);

% pr = Pmed(1,18);

% ps = Pmed(1,19);

% pt = Pmed(1,20);

% pu = Pmed(1,21);

% pv = Pmed(1,22);

% px = Pmed(1,23);

% py = Pmed(1,24);

% pw = Pmed(1,25);

% pz = Pmed(1,26);

LacLido = dat(:,3:2:end);

aa = LacLido(:,1); %Selecionando Indivíduos e suas [LAC];

ab = LacLido(:,2);

ac = LacLido(:,3);

ad = LacLido(:,4);

ae = LacLido(:,5);

af = LacLido(:,6);

ag = LacLido(:,7);

ah = LacLido(:,8);

% ai = LacLido(:,9);

% aj = LacLido(:,10);

% ak = LacLido(:,11);

% al = LacLido(:,12);

% am = LacLido(:,13);

% an = LacLido(:,14);

% ao = LacLido(:,15);

% ap = LacLido(:,16);

% aq = LacLido(:,17);

% ar = LacLido(:,18);

% as = LacLido(:,19);

% at = LacLido(:,20);

% au = LacLido(:,21);

% av = LacLido(:,22);

% ax = LacLido(:,23);

% ay = LacLido(:,24);

% aw = LacLido(:,25);

% az = LacLido(:,26);

caa = (((aa.*Cal)./pa).*3); %Corrigindo [LAC] e depois agrupando os resultados;

cab = (((ab.*Cal)./pb).*3);

cac = (((ac.*Cal)./pc).*3);

cad = (((ad.*Cal)./pd).*3);

cae = (((ae.*Cal)./pe).*3);

caf = (((af.*Cal)./pf).*3);

cag = (((ag.*Cal)./pg).*3);

cah = (((ah.*Cal)./ph).*3);

% cai = (((ai.*Cal)./pi).*3);

% caj = (((aj.*Cal)./pj).*3);

% cak = (((ak.*Cal)./pk).*3);

% cal = (((al.*Cal)./pl).*3);

% cam = (((am.*Cal)./pm).*3);

% can = (((an.*Cal)./pn).*3);

% cao = (((ao.*Cal)./po).*3);

% cap = (((ap.*Cal)./pp).*3);

% caq = (((aq.*Cal)./pq).*3);

% car = (((ar.*Cal)./pr).*3);

% cas = (((as.*Cal)./ps).*3);

% cat = (((at.*Cal)./pt).*3);

% cau = (((au.*Cal)./pu).*3);

% cav = (((av.*Cal)./pv).*3);

% cax = (((ax.*Cal)./px).*3);

% cay = (((ay.*Cal)./py).*3);

% caw = (((aw.*Cal)./pw).*3);

% caz = (((az.*Cal)./pz).*3);

LacCor = [caa,cab,cac,cad,cae,caf,cag,cah];%cai,caj,cak,cal,cam,can,cao,cap,caq,car,cas,cat,cau,cav,cax,cay,caw,caz];

pka = max(LacCor(1:3,1)); %Identificando [LAC]pico;

pkb = max(LacCor(1:3,2));

pkc = max(LacCor(1:3,3));

pkd = max(LacCor(1:3,4));

pke = max(LacCor(1:3,5));

pkf = max(LacCor(1:3,6));

pkg = max(LacCor(1:3,7));

pkh = max(LacCor(1:3,8));

% pki = max(LacCor(1:3,9));

% pkj = max(LacCor(1:3,10));

% pkk = max(LacCor(1:3,11));

% pkl = max(LacCor(1:3,12));

% pkm = max(LacCor(1:3,13));

% pkn = max(LacCor(1:3,14));

% pko = max(LacCor(1:3,15));

% pkp = max(LacCor(1:3,16));

% pkq = max(LacCor(1:3,17));

% pkr = max(LacCor(1:3,18));

% pks = max(LacCor(1:3,19));

% pkt = max(LacCor(1:3,20));

% pku = max(LacCor(1:3,21));

% pkv = max(LacCor(1:3,22));

% pkx = max(LacCor(1:3,23));

% pky = max(LacCor(1:3,24));

% pkw = max(LacCor(1:3,25));

% pkz = max(LacCor(1:3,26));

ba = [pka;LacCor(4:end,1)]; %Agrupando [LAC]pico ás [LAC] do incremental;

bb = [pkb;LacCor(4:end,2)];

bc = [pkc;LacCor(4:end,3)];

bd = [pkd;LacCor(4:end,4)];

be = [pke;LacCor(4:end,5)];

bf = [pkf;LacCor(4:end,6)];

bg = [pkg;LacCor(4:end,7)];

bh = [pkh;LacCor(4:end,8)];

% bi = [pki;LacCor(4:end,9)];

% bj = [pkj;LacCor(4:end,10)];

% bk = [pkk;LacCor(4:end,11)];

% bl = [pkl;LacCor(4:end,12)];

% bm = [pkm;LacCor(4:end,13)];

% bn = [pkn;LacCor(4:end,14)];

% bo = [pko;LacCor(4:end,15)];

% bp = [pkp;LacCor(4:end,16)];

% bq = [pkq;LacCor(4:end,17)];

% br = [pkr;LacCor(4:end,18)];

% bs = [pks;LacCor(4:end,19)];

% bt = [pkt;LacCor(4:end,20)];

% bu = [pku;LacCor(4:end,21)];

% bv = [pkv;LacCor(4:end,22)];

% bx = [pkx;LacCor(4:end,23)];

% by = [pky;LacCor(4:end,24)];

% bw = [pkw;LacCor(4:end,25)];

% bz = [pkz;aLacCor(4:end,26)];

b = [ba,bb,bc,bd,be,bf,bg,bh]; %%%%bi,bj,bk,bl,bm,bn,bo,bp,bq,br,bs,bt,bu,bv,bx,by,bw,bz];

Intensidade = dat(3:end,1);

[nl,nc]=size(b);

Intensidade = (Intensidade(1:nl)); %Normalizando a Intensidade;

mpr = [Intensidade,b];

mpr(mpr==0)= NaN; %Identificando zeros e colocando NaN;

v = ~any(isnan(mpr)); %Identificando e excluindo os NaN do polinomio;

da = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,2), 2); %Polinomio;

db = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,3), 2);

dc = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,4), 2);

dd = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,5), 2);

de = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,6), 2);

df = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,7), 2);

dg = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,8), 2);

dh = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,9), 2);

% di = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,10), 2);

% dj = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,11), 2);

% dk = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,12), 2);

% dl = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,13), 2);

% dm = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,14), 2);

% dn = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,15), 2);

% do = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,16), 2);

% dp = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,17), 2);

% dq = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,18), 2);

% dr = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,19), 2);

% ds = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,20), 2);

% dt = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,21), 2);

% du = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,22), 2);

% dv = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,23), 2);

% dx = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,24), 2);

% dy = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,25), 2);

% dw = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,26), 2);

% dz = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,27), 2);

abc = [da;db;dc;dd;de;df;dg;dh]; %;di;dj;dk;dl;dm;dn;do;dp;dq;dr;ds;dt;du;dv;dx;dy;dw;dz];

LacMinA = (abc(1,2)./(2*abc(1,1)));% Determinando LacMin Atleta (A);

LacMinB = (abc(2,2)./(2*abc(2,1)));

LacMinC = (abc(3,2)./(2*abc(3,1)));

LacMinD = (abc(4,2)./(2*abc(4,1)));

LacMinE = (abc(5,2)./(2*abc(5,1)));

LacMinF = (abc(6,2)./(2*abc(6,1)));

LacMinG = (abc(7,2)./(2*abc(7,1)));

LacMinH = (abc(8,2)./(2*abc(8,1)));

%LacMinI = (abc(9,2)./(2*abc(9,1)));

%LacMinJ = (abc(10,2)./(2*abc(10,1)));

%LacMinK = (abc(11,2)./(2*abc(11,1)));

%LacMinL = (abc(12,2)./(2*abc(12,1)));

%LacMinM = (abc(13,2)./(2*abc(13,1)));

%LacMinN = (abc(14,2)./(2*abc(14,1)));

%LacMinO = (abc(15,2)./(2*abc(15,1)));

%LacMinP = (abc(16,2)./(2*abc(16,1)));

%LacMinQ = (abc(17,2)./(2*abc(17,1)));

%LacMinR = (abc(18,2)./(2*abc(18,1)));

%LacMinS = (abc(19,2)./(2*abc(19,1)));

%LacMinT = (abc(20,2)./(2*abc(20,1)));

%LacMinU = (abc(21,2)./(2*abc(21,1)));

%LacMinV = (abc(22,2)./(2*abc(22,1)));

%LacMinX = (abc(23,2)./(2*abc(23,1)));

%LacMinY = (abc(24,2)./(2*abc(24,1)));

%LacMinW = (abc(25,2)./(2*abc(25,1)));

%LacMinZ = (abc(26,2)./(2*abc(26,1)));


LacMin = [LacMinA,LacMinB,LacMinC,LacMinD,LacMinE,LacMinF,LacMinG,LacMinH]; %,LacMinI,LacMinJ,LacMinK,LacMinL,LacMinM,LacMinN,LacMinO,LacMinP,LacMinQ,LacMinR,LacMinS,LacMinT,LacMinU,LacMinV,LacMinX,LacMinY,LacMinW,LacMinZ];

[LacMin] = LacMin./-1

end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do include what you expected to see, what you saw, and what you already tried to do. Also, I doubt anyone is willing to read that much code, so in your own interest, please limit the code in your question to the absolutely essential, probably no more than three or four commands in all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular problem lies here:

```
v = ~any(isnan(mpr)); %Identificando e excluindo os NaN do polinomio;
da = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,2), 2); %Polinomio;
...
```

You're finding *columns* of `mpr` without NaNs, but you then use that mask to index *rows* - the only reason you don't get an error is that at that point `mpr` happens to be a square matrix. If you check [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22437294/3156750) you'll see that `any` takes a dimension as its second argument - that's important.

---

As an aside, since I was running your code to check it, I took the liberty of vectorising it. Isn't this easier to handle? The non-trivial bits are the use of `repmat` to handle the `Pmed` divide changing from vector/scalar to matrix/vector, and the loop since `polyfit` isn't vectorisable.

```
function [LacMin] = lac2(dat)
Cal = 5.0; %Valor de Calibração;
StLido = dat(1:3,2:2:end); %Identificando Padroes;
StLido(StLido==0) = NaN; %Exluindo zeros;
Pmed = repmat(nanmean(StLido), size(dat,1), 1); %Padrão Médio;
LacLido = dat(:,3:2:end);
LacCor = (((LacLido.*Cal)./Pmed).*3); %Corrigindo [LAC] e depois agrupando os resultados;
pka = max(LacCor(1:3,:)); %Identificando [LAC]pico;
b = [pka;LacCor(4:end,:)]; %Agrupando [LAC]pico ás [LAC] do incremental;
Intensidade = dat(3:end,1);
[nl,nc]=size(b);
Intensidade = (Intensidade(1:nl)); %Normalizando a Intensidade;
mpr = [Intensidade,b];
mpr(mpr==0)= NaN; %Identificando zeros e colocando NaN;
v = ~any(isnan(mpr), 2); %Identificando e excluindo os NaN do polinomio;
abc = zeros(nc, 3);
for ii=1:nc
  abc(ii,:) = polyfit(mpr(v,1), mpr(v,ii+1), 2); %Polinomio;
end
LacMin = -(abc(:,2)./(2*abc(:,1)))';% Determinando LacMin Atleta (A);
end
```

I can't *guarantee* this is perfect, since I've made virtually no effort to understand what this code actually *does*, but it's basically just a straight syntax transformation and produces the same result as the original code for the given input. I'd recommend having a look at the difference vectorisation makes in terms of *writing* code - Matlab becomes even more enjoyable once you start making good use of all the things it can do.

Comment: Yeh, perfect! Thank so much! Th best

Comment: Hi Notlikethat, I need help. When I use the your code, there somehow of the plotting the values? For single plots each case?